# Apache2 wildcard + static subdomain

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I would like to have traffic for all subdomains directed to one directory, only for one specific subdomain, to another one.

```
<VirtualHost beta.home.lan:80>
    ServerName beta.home.lan
    DocumentRoot /var/www/beta
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName beta.home.lan
    DocumentRoot /var/www/others
</VirtualHost>
```

It seams that the first virtual serve catches ALL trafic.
What have I done wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#servername:

> “If you are using name-based virtual hosts, the ServerName inside a  section specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to match this virtual host.”

If you request anything else than `beta.home.lan`, neither of the ServerNames in your two VirtualHosts matches – and there for this applies,

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html#using:

> “If no matching virtual host is found, then the first listed virtual host that matches the IP address will be used.”

Use a [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#serveralias) instead in your second VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName beta.home.lan
    DocumentRoot /var/www/beta
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.home.lan
    DocumentRoot /var/www/others
</VirtualHost>
```